# ORA-30928: "Connect by filtering phase runs out of temp tablespace"

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i have created a query that is sued to display a data in a label. This particular query will then be stored into a program that we use. The query runs just fine until this morning when it returns the error ORA-30928: "Connect by filtering phase runs out of temp tablespace". I have Googled and found out that I can do any of the following:

1. Include a NO FILTERING hint - but did not work properly
2. Increase the temp tablespace - not applicable to me since this runs in a production server that I don't have any access to.

Are there other ways to fix this? By the way, below is the query that I use.

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT
gn.wipdatavalue 
, gn.containername 
, gn.l 
, gn.q 
, gn.d 
, gn.l2 
, gn.q2 
, gn.d2 
, gn.l3 
, gn.q3 
, gn.d3 
, gn.old 
, gn.qtyperbox 
, gn.productname 
, gn.slot 
, gn.dt 
, gn.ws_green 
, gn.ws_pnr 
, gn.ws_pcn 
, intn.mkt_number dsn 
, gn.low_number 
, gn.high_number 
, gn.msl
, gn.baketime
, gn.exptime
, NVL(gn.q, 0) + NVL(gn.q2, 0) + NVL(gn.q3, 0) AS qtybox
, row_number () over (partition by slot order by low_number) as n
FROM
(
SELECT
tr.* 
, TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(wipdatavalue, 1, INSTR (wipdatavalue || '-', '-') - 1)) AS low_number
, TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(wipdatavalue, 1 + INSTR ( wipdatavalue, '-'))) AS high_number
, pm.msllevel MSL
, pm.baketime BAKETIME
, pm.expstime EXPTIME
FROM trprinting tr
JOIN CONTAINER c ON tr.containername = c.containername
JOIN a_lotattributes ala ON c.containerid = ala.containerid
JOIN product p ON c.productid = p.productid
LEFT JOIN otherdb.pkg_main pm ON trim(p.brandname) = trim(pm.pcode)
WHERE (c.containername = :lot OR tr.SLOT= :lot)
)gn
LEFT JOIN otherdb.intnr intn ON TRIM(gn.productname) = TRIM(intn.part_number)
connect by level <= HIGH_NUMBER + 1 - LOW_NUMBER and LOW_NUMBER = prior LOW_NUMBER and prior SYS_GUID() is not null
ORDER BY low_number,n
)
WHERE n LIKE :n AND wipdatavalue LIKE :wip AND ROWNUM <= 300 AND wipdatavalue NOT LIKE 0
```

I am using Oracle 11g too.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Why do you have "AND wipdatavalue NOT LIKE 0" in your query? That looks strange (it will only exclude the literal value '0'). Did you mean "AND wipdatavalue NOT LIKE '0%' "?

Comment: Hello Frank, we particularly use the NOT LIKE '0' part of the query to query out all data that has a wipdatavalue of zero. once wrong transactions are made, they can just zero our wipdatavalue so it will not be displayed on the resulting set.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you don't use wipdatavalue != '0' then? Seems more straightforward to me.

Comment: I suggest you check your explain plan and try to tune up your query, from my personal experience having multiple nested subqueries would slow your performance (i.e. more processing/data more tablespace needed)

Comment: Temp tablespace is a shared resource.  It's possible some other queries were using up 99% of the temp tablespace.  You may want to have their DBAs check how much resources were being used before they blame your query.  Also, what's the point of `prior SYS_GUID() is not null`?